# square payments api v2 giving payment process 404 error

Tags: php, payment-gateway, square-connect, square

i am trying to integrate square payments php api in my website, i am using this [source](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/php_payment) i have followed all the steps but it gives me an error when i proceed to payment after inputting all the card details, the console shows /process payment 404 not found, like the one shown below [image]

the payment process file is already in the folder, only change i made from the source is that i used "composer install" instead of "composer.phar install" because that was not working.

can anyone please help on what should be done?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. The repo you referred to, has a file named `process-payment.php` – is that what you are trying to reach, but you specified the URL without the `.php` suffix?

Comment: `process-payment.php` and `process-payment` are different things. What part of your setup should be responsible for mapping the requested URL `process-payment` to the file named `process-payment.php`?

Comment: @CBroe yes the process-payment.php is supposed to be called automatically from the cdn, but it says it cannot be found, while it is in the folder

Comment: it says sqaure.js is the file that is giving the error, if you can see the picture.

square.js is file included via a cdn https://sandbox.web.squarecdn.com/v1/square.js

Comment: Its process-payment.php not process-payment

Comment: _“it says sqaure.js is the file that is giving the error”_ - that’s where the faulty request _originated_. But this file does not appear to contain `process-payment` anywhere, at least not in plain text form. So it probably takes that URL from some configuration variable, and it looks like you simply specified the _wrong_ URL somewhere.

Comment: @Grumpy you can see the error in the picture above, can you please guide me on what i am doing wrong, this happens when i press the payment button

Comment: @CBroe i am fully following the source, it mentions nowhere that there is some other configuration variable that need to be set, and i have searched the files there seems none

Comment: Can you add the source of square.js

Comment: @Grumpy sandbox.web.squarecdn.com/v1/square.js its a cdn

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPS instead of HTTP like https://localhost/square3/php_payment.php

Answer (score -1):

i got a fix to this, there was a fault in the sqaure php api itself, i reached sqaure support, there was a variable that had wrong value on their side, the new and updated code can be found [here](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/php_payment)

Follow the rest of the instructions as documented and it should work fine now.